# What does volume parameter for a real gas equation mean for a fluid flowing in a pipe?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics

I want to understand what the volume means in a $(p,v,T)=0 \ $, for a system of [real gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_gas) flowing in a pipe. Will it be that since the fluid is flowing, $V$, will be the local volume in a given region of the pipe?

Actually, I was expecting volumetric rate to be present in the [EOS](https://ebrary.net/196847/mathematics/equations_state_real_gases) (Equation of State) (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state)) of real gases for flowing fluid, not volume, since the pipe is open ended it has no definite volume for the fluid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lowercase $v$ in this situation is usually either molar volume ($V/n$) or specific volume ($V/M = 1/\rho$). Because it's a ratio of two extensive quantities in either case $v$ is an intensive quantity that can vary with position, like pressure $p$ and temperature $T$.

So, for example, the usual $PV=nRT$ becomes $Pv = RT$ for molar volume, and $Pv=mRT$ with $m$ the mean molar mass when $v$ is the specific volume.

Comment: Please, what does the v/m or v/n mean for for flowing fluid in an open ended pipe

Comment: @Martins It makes take a volume, in principle differentially small, in practice something a little larger than the mean free path cubed, divide that volume by the number of molecules or a mount of mass in it.